# This version of kubeadm only supports deploying clusters with the control plane version >= 1.16.0. Current version: v1.12.0 Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet

I'm trying to initialize a cluster with a configuration file in Kubernetes, The version for the kubeadm,kubectl and kubelet and as following for all nodes.

1.kubeadm

```
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:17:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

2.kubectl

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.3", GitCommit:"2e7996e3e2712684bc73f0dec0200d64eec7fe40", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-05-20T12:52:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

3.kubelet

```
Kubernetes v1.18.3
```

But still Iam getting the error that my control plane version is lesser as mentioned following:

```
this version of kubeadm only supports deploying clusters with the control plane version >= 1.16.0. Current version: v1.12.0
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Why am I getting this error.? Can someone help me with this.Thanks in advance for your time – if I’ve missed out anything, over- or under-emphasised a specific point let me know in the comments.

Comment: is this new installation or you already have a kubeadm installed and trying to upgrade?

Comment: Its a new installation

Comment: share output of kubeadm upgrade plan

Comment: Iam getting an error while doing this 
```
couldn't create a Kubernetes client from file "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf": failed to load admin kubeconfig: open /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf: no such file or directory
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose a specific version of kubernetes control plane during installation by adding `kubernetesVersion` in the kubeadm config file.

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.17.0
apiServer:
...
```

Comment: can not mix '--config' with arguments [kubernetes-version]
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
this is output when I try using the --kubernetes-version

Comment: share the full command you are running...I have updated the answer as well

Comment: kubeadm init  --kubernetes-version=1.17 --config=config.yml

Comment: Okay remove --kubernetes-version=1.17  and add kubernetesVersion:1.17.0 in the config file

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying with a lower version inside the config file,Now  its working.